Why isn't horsepower used as a measure of power output for jet engines?
I don't understand why we can't use hp to measure the power output of a jet engine. Is it because jet engines operate on a different principle from piston engines? What determines the appropriate unit?

Of course you can express the power of a jet engine in horsepower. It is rather impractical, though.
The first step to practical units is to switch to SI units. Power is better measured in Watts, which is equivalent to Newton times meters per second.
Now let's use a fairly common turbofan engine, the JT-15. Its version D has a static thrust at sea level of 12.7 kN. Static means it is motionless, so the power is zero. Better to pick up some speed: At 245 m/s the thrust drops to 8.0 kN. Times the speed this becomes 1.96 MW or 2626 HP.
The purpose of a jet engine is to overcome drag and accelerate an object like an airplane. With 12.7 kN static thrust, you can directly apply Newton's first law when you know the mass of the airplane and determine the acceleration. Say the airplane has a mass of 4000 kg: A JT-15D without significant installation losses will give that airplane an initial take-off acceleration of 3.15 m/s². As you can see, knowing the thrust is more helpful than knowing the power.
Turbojets have approximately constant thrust over the subsonic speed range, so a single figure is all you need to get an idea how well they will power your airplane, regardless of speed. As you can see from the above example, at the same time power will vary wildly over speed, making quick back-of-the-envelope calculations a bit harder.
Why, then, would anyone express engine performance as power? This has to do with piston engines, which are rather unaffected by flight speed and deliver constant power over speed. With them it is easier to express performance in Kilowatts or horsepower, because that figure is now constant over speed. To arrive at the thrust you still need to know the efficiency of the propeller attached to this engine, which in turn is quite variable  over speed.

power depends on the frame of ref. There is also the pumping power (volume times pressure).

@fraxinus ... which would obviously be better for jets. But the thrust times speed sort of power is also used for propeller driven airplanes, necessitating an exception for the static case. And, of course, I wanted to show how much more practical the use of thrust is.
